# Adjust levels for ezcontourf()

Tags: matlab

I'm have some difficulties with something that should be easy.

I'm plotting several contours with the ezcontourf() function. I would like the color scale to be identical for each plot so that it is easy to compare the results.

I have done this with contourf() in the same document simply by using 'LevelList',custom_levels where custom_levels is a vector with level data.

However, ezcontourf() doesn't like this and I can't seem to use h = ezcontourf() either. Any help would be appreciated!

```
wcr = fun(x,y)
figure
ezcontourf(wcr,[0, 250, 0, 250]);
```

Comment: You may need to use `contourf` or `contour`, which do let you specify levels. From the doc: "CONTOUR(X,Y,Z,V) draw a contour line for each
    level specified in vector V"

Comment: I did that already for a different plot where I have x,y,z data. But since this function is symbolic, I would like to use ezcontourf().

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to use caxis([min max])! For future reference.